# Excel formula for check first 2 digits in a code and returns a different text in another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to a formula in excel to check first 2 digits in a set of a long code in one cell and returns a different specific text for different numbers in another cell

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This question has very low quality. Since this is not a script/formula writing service, you will have to update your question with more detail of what you are attempting and what you have tried so far. If you need assistance, take a look at ***[ask]***.

Answer (score 1):

If the string is in cell `A1` then the formula should be:

```
=VLOOKUP(LEFT(A1,2),Sheet2!$A$1:$B$4,2,FALSE)
```

There must be in Sheet2 in columns A and B, the table with the matching of codes and text, something like this:

```
 A       B
33    France
34    Spain
57    Colombia
```

I'm using international phone codes for the example.

Comment: I know you are trying to be helpful, but I don't understand how you can answer this question with so little detail about what the OP is trying to accomplish.